# Stored procedure always returns same query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I tried to write a SQL query to get results with some parameters, but when I send parameters, it doesn't work. It always returns the last query in if else condition statement.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RealEstatesList]
   @TransCode NVARCHAR(5),
   @CatUrl NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
   @ForSaleItem BIT = NULL,
   @NewItem BIT = NULL,
   @ItemOfDay BIT = NULL,
   @Random BIT = NULL,
   @Top INT = NULL
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   SET XACT_ABORT ON  
   SET FMTONLY OFF

   BEGIN TRAN

   IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TempTable
   END

    SELECT 
        R.[ID],
        RT.[Title],
        R.[Price],
        R.[NewItem],
        R.[ForSaleItem],
        R.[ItemOfDay],
        R.[Url],
        (SELECT TOP 1 CC.Url
         FROM [dbo].[Category] CC
         JOIN [dbo].[LinkTypes] LLT ON LLT.[MainID]  = CC.ID
         JOIN [dbo].[Links] LL ON LL.[LinkTypeID] = LLT.[ID]
         JOIN [dbo].[RealEstates] RR  ON RR.[ID] = LL.LinkID
         WHERE LLT.[LinkedTypeID] = 17 
           AND LLT.[MainTypeID] = 1 
           AND RR.ID = R.[ID]) AS 'CatUrl',
        (SELECT TOP 1 
             (SELECT TOP 1 XC.Url 
              FROM Category XC
              JOIN [dbo].[LinkTypes] LLT ON LLT.[MainID]  = XC.ID
              JOIN [dbo].[Links] LL ON LL.[LinkTypeID] = LLT.[ID]
              WHERE LLT.[LinkedTypeID] = 1 
                AND LLT.[MainTypeID] = 1 
                AND LL.LinkID = CC.ID)
         FROM [dbo].[Category] CC
         JOIN [dbo].[LinkTypes] LLT ON LLT.[MainID]  = CC.ID
         JOIN [dbo].[Links] LL ON LL.[LinkTypeID] = LLT.[ID]
         JOIN [dbo].[RealEstates] RR  ON RR.[ID] = LL.LinkID
         WHERE LLT.[LinkedTypeID] = 17 
           AND LLT.[MainTypeID] = 1 
           AND RR.ID = R.[ID]) AS 'PCatUrl'
   INTO 
       #TempTable
   FROM 
       [dbo].[RealEstates] R 
   JOIN
       [dbo].[RealEstatesT] RT ON R.[ID] = RT.[RealEsID]
   JOIN
       [dbo].[LinkTypes] LT ON LT.[MainTypeID] = 17
   JOIN 
       [dbo].[Links] L ON L.[LinkTypeID] = LT.[ID]
   JOIN
       [dbo].[Translation] TR ON TR.[ID] = RT.[TransID]
   WHERE 
       R.[Active] = 1
       AND R.[Deleted] = 0
       AND RT.[Deleted] = 0
       AND LT.[LinkedTypeID] = 5 
       AND LT.[MainID]  = R.[ID]
       AND TR.[ShortName] = @TransCode
   GROUP BY
       R.[ID], RT.[Title], R.[Price], R.[NewItem], R.[ForSaleItem], R.[ItemOfDay], R.[Url]


   if (@Top = null or @Top = 0)
   begin
      set @Top = 100000;
   end


   if(@NewItem != null)
   begin
      select TOP (@Top) [ID],[Title],[Price],[NewItem],[ForSaleItem],[CatUrl],[PCatUrl],[ItemOfDay],[Url]
      from #TempTable
      where NewItem = @NewItem
      order by case when @Random = 1 then NEWID() end
   end

   else if(@ForSaleItem != null)
   begin
      select TOP (@Top) [ID],[Title],[Price],[NewItem],[ForSaleItem],[CatUrl],[PCatUrl],[ItemOfDay],[Url]
      from #TempTable
      where ForSaleItem = @ForSaleItem
      order by case when @Random = 1 then NEWID() end
   end

   else if(@CatUrl != null)
   begin
      select TOP (@Top) [ID],[Title],[Price],[NewItem],[ForSaleItem],[CatUrl],[PCatUrl],[ItemOfDay],[Url]
      from #TempTable
      where CatUrl = @CatUrl or PCatUrl = @CatUrl
      order by case when @Random = 1 then NEWID() end
   end

   else if(@ItemOfDay != null)
   begin
      select TOP (@Top) [ID],[Title],[Price],[NewItem],[ForSaleItem],[CatUrl],[PCatUrl],[ItemOfDay],[Url]
      from #TempTable
      where ItemOfDay = @ItemOfDay
      order by case when @Random = 1 then NEWID() end
   end

   else
   begin
      select TOP (@Top) [ID],[Title],[Price],[NewItem],[ForSaleItem],[CatUrl],[PCatUrl],[ItemOfDay],[Url]
      from #TempTable
      order by case when @Random = 1 then NEWID() end
   end

COMMIT
```

Transcode and Random parameters work well but CatUrl, ForSaleItem, NewItem, ItemOfDay parameters does not work. It always returns the last query in if else condition statement.

Hope you can help. I'm waiting for your answers.

***edit :***

I changed all my null checks like "NULLIF(@Top, '') IS NULL" and now if statements works well.

Comment: you should check for `NULL` using `IS NOT NULL` and not `!=`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thanks Squirrel i changed them like you said and it works well now. thank you :)